# Firebase Messaging on Android suddenly started crashing when message received

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, abstractmethoderror

Currently using react native, react-native-firebase, and react-native-push-notification. Everything was fine until suddenly today firebase messaging started causing the app to crash. The error message is the following:

```
    Process: com.packagename, PID: 30087
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.iid.WithinAppServiceBinder$IntentHandler.zza(android.content.Intent)"
        at com.google.firebase.iid.WithinAppServiceBinder.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:9)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzaw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:30)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzaw.onServiceConnected(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:59)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:2067)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:2099)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

The error occurs when a notification is received, but does not trigger a data message. In addition, the notification is received and processed before causing the crash.

I thought the error might have been caused by changing the react-native-firebase/app version, so I reverted my project on git to that of a previous, working version. However, I still get the same error after cleaning and rebuilding. It also occurs even if there are no notification listeners set up on the react native side, although I'm not sure what that entails for the actual native code. What could possibly be the problem? I'm using versions of react-native-firebase/messaging (7.1.5) and react-native-firebase/app (7.2.0) that were previously functional.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We tried adding `firebaseMessagingVersion = "20.2.1"` into the ext section in the root project `android/build.gradle` which fixed it for us. We looked into the `safeExtGet` method and found that it would try to extract the top level variable from the root project file.

By doing it in this way we didn't need to touch the node modules.

```
ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
        firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "20.2.1"
    }
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing as well, will mark this as the correct answer

Comment: I had the same issue and this saved my butt. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, downgrading worked. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Downgrading is the correct solution, see my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 45):

**Edit 07/09/2020**: We have released `firebase-iid` and `firebase-messaging` versions `20.2.3` with a fix for this issue, please upgrade to the latest versions.

---

[Firebaser here] It looks like yesterday's releases of `firebase-messaging` and `firebase-iid` contain a bug which can cause this crash.  We are working hard on a fix.

For now the best thing to do is to use the versions released on June 18th:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2020-06-18

- `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1`
- `com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.2.1`

We are working on a fix and hope to have a new release out soon. When we do I will update this answer and the release notes will be available here:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Thanks for the update @sam-stern! I'm also having this issue, so please let us know whenever you have news 

Comment: Can the firebase Iid be set also with adding `firebaseIidVersion = "20.2.1"`  to the `android/build.gradle`?

Answer (score 12):

Exact same issue with these versions. And yes they were functional before this
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.7.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.7.1",

Issue Solved:

1. Go to react-native-push-notification/build.gradle
2. Change
   def firebaseVersion = safeExtGet('firebaseVersion', '+')
   to
   def firebaseVersion = safeExtGet('firebaseVersion', '20.2.1')

It was picking us the version 20.2.2 which is not stable and was causing all kind of weird issues.

Comment: wow this did it thanks so much! I was going insane because of this.

Comment: By the way for me it was firebaseMessagingVersion, in case anyone else sees this and has the same issue

Comment: Thanks! @tenkay I had to do the same as you, `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${safeExtGet('firebaseMessagingVersion', '20.2.1')}"`

Comment: Wouldn't this just get wiped when you reinstall node modules? Also it wouldn't be committed to version control (assuming you'd git-ignore node_modules). I'm new to RN, maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Yes it would get wiped, In this case I would recommend following the accepted answer but if you ever need to change anything in node_modules, patch-package is a convenient solution

Answer (score 5):

This upgrade fixed the issue for me

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3'
```

Comment: This worked for me. Been scratching my head for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

This case is working for me:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4"
```

Ref [to github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1460#issuecomment-658786980)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed with latest version of this dependency.
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v20-2-3