# React Native: Firebase notification click crashes the app when in app is in foreground. - Looking for permanent solution

Tags: push-notification, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase for one of my React Native project, Everything was working perfectly till today.
Suddenly the app's push notification started acting weirdly.

**ERROR**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app, PID: 7389
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.iid.WithinAppServiceBinder$IntentHandler.zza(android.content.Intent)"
        at com.google.firebase.iid.WithinAppServiceBinder.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:9)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzaw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:30)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzaw.onServiceConnected(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:59)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1948)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1980)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**`android/build.gradle`**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"
        googlePlayServicesVersion   = "16.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
    }
}
```

**`app/build.gradle`**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.2'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.2"
```

PS: React with firebase act weird.

Comment: I found the solution but it is not permanent.
Temporary solution is:
Inside react-native-push-notification/build.gradle change _20.2.1_ instead of _+_ on this line
`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${safeExtGet('firebaseMessagingVersion', '20.2.1')}"`

Comment: You can find a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767041/firebase-messaging-on-android-suddenly-started-crashing-when-message-received

Comment: Thanks @Leg3nd but see the comment I already have checked that answer in above comment and it is a **temporary** solution.