# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task Firebase after update

Tags: java, android, firebase, build.gradle

After updating the following dependencies :

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
```

The app crash at run time with :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.iid.WithinAppServiceBinder$IntentHandler.zza(android.content.Intent)"
        at com.google.firebase.iid.WithinAppServiceBinder.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:9)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzaw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:30)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzaw.onServiceConnected(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:59)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1830)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Messaging on Android suddenly started crashing when message received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767041/firebase-messaging-on-android-suddenly-started-crashing-when-message-received)

Comment: @ShaluTD it's about react-native

Comment: You should downgrade firebase dependencies

Comment: @ShaluTD yeah, that what I've done

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI I tried to downgrade the dependencies but not working. Can you share which version you are using for firebase messaging and firebase-auth

Comment: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'`

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI by any chance, are you using One Signal ?

Comment: @Gersard, no I didn't use it, the issue is already solved months ago, just update the Firebase libraries

Answer (score 3):

```
If you updated library and getting error then try below code.It is worked for me.
 
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

Comment: Currently use `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.3`.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same crash reports with firebase-core:17.4.4 , i downgraded it to 17.4.3 and they disappeared .

the crash wasn't systematic though, only during automatic testing as far as I know