# firebase crashes on phones on first app launch

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

This is quite weird.
I have integrated firebase with android studio wizard. It works perfectly on tablets but when I run app on the phone it throws following:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rhyboo.net.puzzleplus, PID: 26597
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.iid.WithinAppServiceBinder$IntentHandler.zza(android.content.Intent)"
        at com.google.firebase.iid.WithinAppServiceBinder.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:9)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzaw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:30)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzaw.onServiceConnected(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.2:59)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1948)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1980)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

This happens even if I comment all code and leave empty `onCreate`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Even stranger that the crash occurs only on the first app launch. Futher launches go with no crashes

Comment: it _might_ be useful to others to see your build.gradle file to see your firebase dependencies

Comment: Are you using firebase-messaging / firebase-iid 20.2.2? If so, you should switch to 20.2.3 or 20.2.1 See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62797685/1524450

Comment: Hey Michael. That's it! It was firebase-messaging:20.2.2.Could you post your comment as an answer?Thank you